# How to show the appropriate date in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

In my smarty template, `{$u.doj}` will output the date the user joined my site.

For example,

`{$u.doj}` will output `2014-06-19 09:41:04`.

`{$u.doj|nicetime}` will output `1 month ago`.

How can I output **Jun 19, 2014**? I'm interested in a easy way using already predefined smarty functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
{$u.doj|date_format:"%b %d, %Y"}
```

More you can read at [date_format in Smarty reference](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl)